# installing Oracle database 12c on centos7 server (vps)

Tags: installation, centos7, oracle12c, putty, vps

I want to install the Oracle 12C database by putty on a centos 7 server (vps) .
Although there seems to be enough space for installation,but the installation is not done .According to the errors, please help me if you know the problem

> 1: [INS-32021]Installer has detected that the available disk space on the volume for Oracle home
> Action-Choose a location for Oracle home that has enough space(minimum of 12.130MB) or free up space on the existing volume.
>
> 2: [INS-35212]Insufficient disk space on this volume for the selected datafiles location
> Cause- The selected datafiles location was on a volume without enough disk space
> Action-Choose a location for datafiles that has enough space(minimum of 12.130MB) or free up space on the existing volume

The server memory specification is as follows :

```
[root@localhost ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        234M     0  234M   0% /dev
tmpfs           244M     0  244M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           244M   29M  215M  12% /run
tmpfs           244M     0  244M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda1        25G   14G  9.9G  58% /
tmpfs            49M     0   49M   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs            49M     0   49M   0% /run/user/1000
```

i have 9G space on /dev/vda1 , but can not install

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which volume you were attempting to install into, but the *bare minimum* required disk space for Oracle database software us 7.5GB, per the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/ladbi/storage-checklist-for-oracle-database-installation.html#GUID-C6184DFA-45A2-4420-99D6-237EA5BAB058.

The only partition you show with enough space is the root '/' partition, which would be almost completely (~90%) filled by this installation. A root partition that full will have a drastic affect on OS performance. It is also likely that between OS logs and Oracle log files your root partition will fill up to 100% quickly, and cause the server to hang.

To avoid causing problems for the operating system, Oracle always recommends installing into a dedicated partition (NEVER root), and if possible placing your data files (not included in that 7.5GB) in yet another partition. Oracle also generates a lot of log and trace files, and will need additional space for patch installations, etc.

In order to have enough space for everything with room to grow, Oracle recommends having 100GB of dedicated disk space (see their note in the documentation link above), *just for the software*. Space for your data files for your database(s) (2-3GB minimum for demo db) would be in *addition* to that, as would the recommended swap space (2GB minimum recommended).

Comment: Thank you for your help and you were right. My problem was solved by adding hard memory